# Setup callback for every method call use MOQ

Tags: c#, .net, moq

Is there a way to attach a callback to every method of a mock without having setup each method? E.g.

```
var serviceMock = new Mock<IService>();    
var count = 0;

//method does not exist, but you get the picture
serviceMock.CallbackAllMethods( () => { count++; throw new WebException()}; )
```

Comment: Just interesting - why are you adding callback to all methods of some object?

Comment: I am using a Castle.DynamicProxy to add retry behavior to every method call of a class.  I want to write a test that uses to reflection to call every method and assert that the retry logic executed correctly. I don't care what the args to each method are, just that it is called. So, in a nutshell I'm testing the Interceptor.

Answer (score 1):

[AutoFixture](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/) has nice integration with Moq and will automatically setup methods like this.

There's a good introduction [here on Mark Seemann's blog](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/08/19/AutoFixtureAsAnAutomockingContainer.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting, not sure if (or perhaps how) it does what I need.  I want to create a Mock and have every method call to it throw an exception, but I don't want to have to setup every method??

Comment: If you just need every method to throw an exception, you can create a Strict mock and it will throw for any methods not setup with an expectation.

Comment: Good point, but I need to do some other work in the delegate and throw various types of exceptions too.  Question edited accordingly.